# Using Powershell with FireDaemon

Tags: java, powershell

Is there any way to use Powershell to check the executable directory set in FireDaemon?

I need it to verify which version of Java (jre6, jre7, or jre8) that the application is using before executing the rest of the function.

Thanks!

Update:

It looks like the information I need is in System Information under Loaded Modules.  In there it shows multiple instances of Java and what version is actively being used.  Any way to tap into that via powershell and scan for anything not using version 8?

Comment: So that was able to show me all the installed versions of Java but not which one was being used for a specific application, which is the issue.  I already know there are old instances of Java installed, but I need to check and make sure no apps are using them before running the rest of my script.  Thank you though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve my own question without interacting with FireDaemon:

```
foreach ($server in $servers) {

        $Keys = Get-ChildItem HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\services -Recurse -Include "Parameters" -EA SilentlyContinue
        $Items = $Keys | Foreach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PsPath }
        ForEach ($Item in $Items) {
        $Item.ServiceExe
        }

        if($Item.ServiceExe -like "*jre6*", "*jre1.6*", "*jre1.7*", "*jre7*", "*jdk1.6*", "*jdk1.7*") {
            write-host "Cannot continue, old Java is in use"
        } else {
            write-host "Verified old Java is not in use, continuing..."
            findJava -servers $servers}
        }
```